# Error while using searchKitManager in React

Tags: reactjs, go, elasticsearch, react-admin, searchkit

I am trying to use the [searchKitManager](http://docs.searchkit.co/stable/)  inside react-admin I provided the parameters etc according to the docs but when I run the code it throws errors. Here is how the code works

- React Admin is running on `http://localhost:3000`
- Golang backend is running on `http://localhost:3006`
- ElasticSearch is running on `http://localhost:9200`

When data is inserted in mysql database using golang code it is also inserted in elasticsearch later on in one of my display component I call the above searchkitManager as follows

```
let apiUrl= 'http://localhost:9200/donate' // what link should I pass, url to elasticsearch or url to my backend
const searchkit = new SearchkitManager('/', {
  searchUrlPath: `${apiUrl}/_search`,
});
```

This code will throw `404 Not Found or 400 Bad Request` error but the API works in postman
if I change the above link to

```
let apiUrl= 'http://localhost:9200/donate' // what link should I pass, url to elasticsearch or url to my backend
const searchkit = new SearchkitManager('/', {
  searchUrlPath: `${apiUrl}/_doc/`,
});
```

I am not getting anything at all sometimes it no error in console and sometimes `400 Bad Request or 405 Post Not Allowed`

One last thing the link I am providing as for `searchUrlPath` should be like that or not? or should I pass the `apiUrl` in place of `/`? I tried that as well but just to make sure.

Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I have not used `searchKitManager`. But my first response to seeing a 400 is to check API logs and figure out why is there a 400 in the first place. A 400 is something that's deliberate by the API (assuming the API has followed REST principles)

Comment: Yeah that is true but the thing is that its SearchKitManager is calling the APIs of ElasticSearch by itself and it seems I am not able to see that

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
const elasticSearchUrl =  'http://localhost:9200/<your_index>';

const searchkit = new SearchkitManager(elasticSearchUrl );
```